# How to create a group and sets the permissions for different users?

Tags: permissions, users

I would like to create group for some user

```
addgroup name
```

After that I would like to add some user to group

```
sudo adduser username groupname
```

And set the permissions for each group. There will be three groups:

1. Group administrators, with permission r,w,e
2. Group of users, they could copy, insert new file, but no rewrite and delete
3. Group of viewers, they could only read.

It will be for folder with subfolders. Could you help me with setting the permissions?

Answer (score -1):

One way you could do that is by using the chmod command. It works like this:

chmod [OPTION]... MODE[,MODE]... FILE...

Then you could have the viewers group have other permission, the users group have regular permission, and the administrators group have root permissions.
I hope this helped with your problem!